# Manage Products Errors in Admin (M2)

Tags: magento2, products-management

We are having trouble with managing products in admin in M2

When we go to a Product and press Save & Duplicate (so we can make a new product, and carryover most of the previous settings). It takes us to a blank page with plain text that says "product save after". And does not complete the action.

Also, when we use the Action dropdown to try and Delete a single product, (or any other action) -- We get HTTP 500 error.

Any thoughts?  Thank you for any input.